# Find values in formula $x * z_1 = y * z_2$

Tags: number-theory

I'm working on a number generator for this little formula

$x * z_1 = y * z_2$

The numbers are within this ranges:

$x \in \{1, ..., 10\}$
$y \in \{1, ..., 10\}$
$z_1 \in \{2, ..., 100\}$
$z_2 \in \{2,...,100\}$

I'm currently just running a brute force algorithmen which chooses $x, z_1$ and $z_2$ randomly out of their ranges and try to find the first number in between 1 and 10. If no matching number is found I just start the algorithmen again.

That works pretty OK but is not a nice solution.

How can I find a better algorithmen? Bonus: How can I find an algorithmen which generates formulas of the pattern:
$x \oplus  z_1 = y \oplus  z_2$ where $\oplus \in \{*, +, -, \div\}$? How do you tackle problems like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have no further restrictions, you could just choose $x$ and $y$ randomly and set $z_2=2x$ and $z_1=2y$. Here, the $2$ just grants that $z_1$ and $z_2$ are not equal to $1$. If you want to make it a bit more general, you could choose a random $m\in\{2,\cdots,10\}$ and set $z_2=mx$ and $z_1=my$.
An even more sophisticated way would be to choose $x$ and $y$ randomly, compute $g=gcd(x,y)$ and set $z_2=m\frac xg$ and $z_1=m\frac yg$ with $1<m\leq 10g$.

For addition and substraction it is considerably simpler, since you can choose $x$, $y$ and $z_1$ and will always get a $z_2$. You will only have to worry about the range a bit.

Division is equivalent to multiplication by bringing $z_1$ and $z_2$ on the other side. Again you might want to change the range here (and be possibly careful with the number 0).

Comment: Implemented like you suggested. Worked like a charm :-) Any suggestions how I can learn to tackle such problems?

Comment: Right now I find it harder to understand what you mean by 'such problems' than to actually answer the question. I guess one thing to keep in mind is that any number can be written as the product of prime numbers and the primes on both sides must be in correspondence. So if you pick $x$, say, then $y$ and $z_2$ together have to have all prime factors of $x$ as prime factors. The easiest way, of course, is that one of them is already a multiple of $x$.